# Python how do you find the max value of population in a txt. file that has records of each state with its abbreviation and population

Tags: python, python-3.x

here is the first record

```
Alabama
AL
4802982
Alaska
AK
721523
```

here is what I have so far:

```
def main():
    state_file = open('StateCensus2010.txt', 'r')
    maxx = 0
    state = state_file.readline()

    while state != '':
        abb = state_file.readline()
        population = int(state_file.readline()) 
        state = state.rstrip('\n') 
        abb = abb.rstrip('\n')

        for population in state_file:
            while maxx <= population:
                maxx = population

        state = state_file.readline()

        print(state) 
        print(abb)
        print(population)

    state = state_file.readline()
    state_file.close() 

main()
```

Comment: You lost me right at `for population in state_file`. Can you explain in words what you think that statement (and the next ones) will do?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number is always contained on the third line, and that the two precedent lines are the state and its abbreviation:

```
## module used to convert read strings into numbers
import ast

## initiate a line counter
counter = -1

## initiate a list, to build the final response of the script
answer = ['statename','stateabbreviation',0]

## open the document
state_file = open('StateCensus2010.txt','r')

## get the lines for index access
lines = state_file.readlines()

## iterate through each line, and if it is a population line number, check it
for line in state_file:
  ## increment the counter by one at the start of each line iteration, to know
  ## kind of line we're dealing with
  counter += 1
  ## if the currently iterated line is a population number line
  if (counter + 1) % 3 == 0:
    ## get the number, and compare with the current one to see if bigger
    population = ast.literal_eval(line)
    if population > answer[2]:
      ## if bigger, replace the answer list with the corresponding data
      ## update state name
      answer[0] = lines[counter-2]
      ## update state abbreviation
      answer[1] = lines[counter-1]
      ## update biggest population number
      answer[2] = population

## close the file
state_file.close()

## And at the end of the script, get the answer:
print ("The state " + answer[0] + " (" + answer[1] + ") has the biggest population of all (" + answer[3] + ")")
```

Comment: oh and if you need to strip the line breaks at the end of each iterated line, simply add line = line[:-2] at the beginning of each corresponding iteration